# Is there an easy way to switch desktops on the remote computer using "back to my mac"

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, back-to-my-mac

I have just setup "back to my mac" and the connection works fine. My only "complaint" so far is that I haven't found a convenient way to switch from one desktop to another on the remote computer (or to any other full-screen app). Clicking on the icon in the dock works. But I was wondering if I missed some other way.

Answer (score 1):

The key command is control and left arrow or right arrow.

You can customize things further in Mission Control preferences as well.

Depending on which VNC/RDC client you are using - the command keys might act locally if you are browsing from OS X - so you might need to eliminate multiple screens to pass those through.

Alternatively, you can use/set a hot key for mission control and choose which screen you want from the top of the window. Changing the local shortcut will allow it to pass through to the remote OS X if that's blocking you.

Comment: I **am** browsing from OS X and **do** have the "pass-through" problems. I looked into changing the local shortcut for Mission Control as you suggested, but I was a bit uncomfortable with that. In the meantime, I discovered one can drag the Mission Control icon from the Applications folder to the Dock on the remote machine. That works well for me.

Comment: @mef Nice - I forgot to add that option. Feel free to put that as an answer and select it or edit it in to my post. Glad you're in business.

Comment: Since you (with 1,000 times the reputation of me) have given me "permission," I have answered my question and accepted my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One can drag the Mission Control icon from the Applications folder to the Dock on the remote machine. By clicking on that icon one then has access to all the screens. That works well for me.